# TypeTags of type aliases with an upper type bound

Tags: scala, reflection, types, scala-2.10

I'm trying to get the TypeTag for a type alias with an upper type bound in a library class. The (simplified) library code looks like:

```
abstract class A {
  trait B
  type T <: B
  def newT: T
}
object A {
  def apply() = new A {
    class B2 extends B
    type T = B2
    def newT = new B2
  }
}
class E[T: TypeTag](x: T)
```

On the REPL I'm doing:

```
val a = A()
val t = a.newT
val e = new E(t)
```

And I get back "No TypeTag available for a.T"

You can think of class `A` as some container (e.g. Map) and of the apply method in the companion object as creating the actual implementation (e.g. HashMap). `B` would be like `MapEntry` in this analogy and I want to construct put this `MapEntry` into another container that asks for the `TypeTag` of the given element.

I hope the idea is clear. Is there a way to do this?

I'm using Scala 2.10.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You example actually works when you define the subclass of `A` explicitly, like this:

```
object A {
  class Ab extends A {
    class B2 extends B
    type T = B2
    def newT = new B2
  }
  def apply() = new Ab
}
```

Alternatively you could use a WeakTypeTag, like this:

```
class E[T: WeakTypeTag](x: T)
```

For details see also this [issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6649).

Comment: Thanks Volker for the answer. I'm still wondering why it doesn't work then since the anonymous class in code I showed was just to make the question more concise, but in the real code a subclass of `A` is defined explicitly and I still get that error.

Comment: Do you know why in the link it says that the compiler "cannot create a TypeTag referring to local class B"?

Comment: Why is WeakTypeTag required here?

Comment: As far as I understand you cant get a `TypeTag` of a local class. I am not sure, but this might be related to the fact that in scala inner classes are bound to the [outer object](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/115). That means to use `TypeTag`s you have to define the subclass of `A` at top-level.